# Multi-line quotes always show up in a single line

Tags: support, formatting, blockquote

I expect the following quote to have 2 lines:

```
> line1
> line2
```

But it actually renders as a single line:

> line1
> line2

I assume this to be a bug since it defeats all my expectations of quoting behavior.

If it is not a bug, how do I get this to behave correctly?

Comment: Two spaces after `line1`.

Comment: Do you have a link to relevant documentation? This does not mention it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks). (It is not about quotes specifically, but about line breaks in general.)

Comment: Would it be a terrible idea to re-phrase this question from what it is now to a discussion on whether blockquotes should not have automatic line breaks?
Or, to cut it short, why don't you post an answer and i'll accept it? (I personally don't think, this behavior is all that self-explanatory, and I have been struggling with this for... a long time before actually asking and learning how this work correctly)

Comment: Better use a trailing "\" (supported now) to not be dependent on significant trailing white space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules regarding line breaks in quotes is the same as outside of quotes. If you want to have a single newline, you need to either **add two spaces after the preceding line**, or add a `<br>`. This is explained in the [Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) under "[Linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks)".

(As far as I'm aware, this is part of Markdown itself, not necessarily Stack Overflow's implementation of it.)

Comment: A third way: A trailing "\" ([backslash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backslash#Noun)) is supported now (likely due to the [switch to CommonMark in June 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)). From the [CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#hard-line-breaks): *"For a more visible alternative, a backslash before the line ending may be used instead of two spaces"*